# Regex to split a string into 3 parts

Tags: java, regex

I have an example dynamic input of information like this:

> Xbox 360 (black) Elite Console 120GB (Mason City Illinois ) $200
>
> $200 2013 North Trail Camper (RT 202. Manchester, Maine) $224/mo.
>
> Snowmobile Bike trailers (Winthrop / Augusta) $40 Monthly
>
> "Great Xmas Gift" XBox 360 Guitar Hero (Springfied)

I am trying to use Regex in Android to split the string into three parts:

1. Text before XXX()
2. Text in (XXX)
3. Text after () XXX

Sometimes there won't be a price, the text after the location in ().

I've tried to

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\(([^]*)\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(title);
```

But I can't get matchers to work in Android. It always returns empty when I look in with `matcher.group(1)`. I have it setup currently to look for either ( or $ and explode too give me the separate strings. But this is inaccurate and inefficient.

Any help is apperciated!

Comment: I assume you want to include `(Mason City Illinois )` but exclude `(black)` ?

Comment: Yes exactly, that is one of the issues I've run into

Comment: I suspect you want only the last `()` to be parsed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you could do this with a regular expression, but it might be simpler not to.

```
    String input[] = {
            "Xbox 360 (black) Elite Console 120GB (Mason City Illinois ) $200",
            "$200 2013 North Trail Camper (RT 202. Manchester, Maine) $224/mo.",
            "Snowmobile Bike trailers (Winthrop / Augusta) $40 Monthly",
            "\"Great Xmas Gift\" XBox 360 Guitar Hero (Springfied)"
    };
    for (String s : input) {
        int lastClose = s.lastIndexOf(')');
        int lastOpen = s.lastIndexOf('(', lastClose);
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, lastOpen).trim() +
                "~" + s.substring(lastOpen + 1, lastClose).trim() +
                "~" + s.substring(lastClose + 1).trim());
    }
```

prints

```
Xbox 360 (black) Elite Console 120GB~Mason City Illinois~$200
$200 2013 North Trail Camper~RT 202. Manchester, Maine~$224/mo.
Snowmobile Bike trailers~Winthrop / Augusta~$40 Monthly
"Great Xmas Gift" XBox 360 Guitar Hero~Springfied~
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that there will always be 3 groups then this expression will work:

(.*)\((.*)\)(.*)

You can try it yourself here:

http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDgsSBlJlY2lwZRiU8y0M/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need to use regex, but if you don't why not use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). Then you can use `"\\(|\\)"` to split the string on parentheses and then get the various sections from the created string array.

Comment: This was my original method, but as you see in the first item it has two sets of parens and string split wouldn't handle that well.

Answer (score 1):

**[Edit]** I wouldn't use regular expressions for this problem; instead I would simply use the [`String#lastIndexOf(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) method to find the bounds of the last `(` and `)` characters and return substrings from those values:

```java
public static String[] splitParens(String s) { 
  if (s == null) return null;
  int indexOfLastOpenParen = s.lastIndexOf('(');
  int indexOfLastCloseParen = s.lastIndexOf(')');
  return new String[] { 
    s.substring(0, indexOfLastOpenParen),
    s.substring(indexOfLastOpenParen + 1, indexOfLastCloseParen),
    s.substring(indexOfLastCloseParen + 1)
  };
} 
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception { 
  String input[] = { 
    "Xbox 360 (black) Elite Console 120GB (Mason City Illinois ) $200",
    "$200 2013 North Trail Camper (RT 202. Manchester, Maine) $224/mo.",
    "Snowmobile Bike trailers (Winthrop / Augusta) $40 Monthly",
    "\"Great Xmas Gift\" XBox 360 Guitar Hero (Springfied)"
  };
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(([^\\)]+)\\)");
  for (String s : input) { 
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(splitParens(s)));
  }
  // =>
  // [Xbox 360 (black) Elite Console 120GB , Mason City Illinois ,  $200]
  // [$200 2013 North Trail Camper , RT 202. Manchester, Maine,  $224/mo.]
  // [Snowmobile Bike trailers , Winthrop / Augusta,  $40 Monthly]
  // ["Great Xmas Gift" XBox 360 Guitar Hero , Springfied, ]
}
```

Of course, more error checking is needed (e.g. what if there is no `(` or `)`?).

Comment: It needs to split on the last (), not the first.

Comment: Yes, The first line splits so Black would be the location and elite console... $200 would be the price which I'm trying to avoid

Comment: @Nick: got it; I just updated my answer but it looks like PeterLawrey beat me to the punch!

Comment: Good idea, you might want to trim() the fields as well. ;)